# Magento REST API - Unable to Login using buyer username and password

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

We are trying to use the REST API for building a Mobile App. I'm able to retrieve the product list using following URL /api/rest/products *as a guest*.

However if i try to retrieve the product list as a ***customer*** using the following code which i got from magento tutorial, it ask for a user login. But even after entering a valid user name and password it just redirect to the login page of the website. What could be the issue? Am i missing some configuration changes.

I have done following steps to configure the REST API.

1. Went to System-> Web Services -> REST Roles. Selected customer and
   under Roles and Resources selected All
2. Went to System -> Web Service -> REST Attributes. Selected Customer,
   under **ACL Attribute Rules** selected ALL for **Resource Access**
3. Went to System -> Web Service -> REST OAuth Consumer and added a new
   Consumer.

And in the following code i have used the key and secret from the consumer.
When i run this code i can view a screen where i required to enter a  email and password. I have entered a email and password which is listed under **Customers -> Manage Customers**. But when click login it just redirects to original page. Please see the images below

REST Login Page
[image]

Page after login it redirects to following page
[image]

```
    $callbackUrl = "http://localhost/mage_lab/magento/"; 
    $siteURL =  "http://localhost/mage_lab/magento";
    $temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "$siteURL/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl); 
    $adminAuthorizationUrl = "$siteURL/oauth/authorize"; 
    $accessTokenRequestUrl = "$siteURL/oauth/token"; 
    $apiUrl = "$siteURL/api/rest"; 
    $consumerKey = '3e234c9aa0e357306757765d0fbec702'; 
    $consumerSecret = '64e191eeb09d489c8fb876ac10ffecee';

    session_start(); 
    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
         $_SESSION['state'] = 0; 
    } 
    try {
        $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
        $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
        $oauthClient->enableDebug();

        if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
            $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
            $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
            $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
            header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
            exit;
        } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
            $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
            $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
            $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
            $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
            $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
            header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
            exit;
        } else {
            $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
            echo $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products/";
            //$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl);
            $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'));
            $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
            print_r($productsList);
        } 
    } 
    catch (OAuthException $e) {
        print_r($e);
        exit;
    }
```

**EDIT**
It working if i already login from website and then try to run the API code. Then it will directly show the Page with Authorize button instead of login page

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think i have found a solution, but not sure if I'm following the proper method. After analyzing i have found two problems with current customer login.

When tried to login as a customer from API login screen, the form does not pass field form_key.

After setting the form key the user will be able to login however the page will be redirected to Accounts page which is not wanted for REST API.

So i have edited

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login.phtml

And added following code under form tag

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo age::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()?>"/>
```

Then overridden

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
```

And altered following code

```
$session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
     $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
}
```

To this :

```
$session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
       $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
 }

 if($this->getRequest()->getPost('oauth_token')){
    $apiAuthorizeURL = age::getBaseUrl().'oauth/authorize?oauth_token='.$this->getRequest()->getPost('oauth_token');
    $session->setAfterAuthUrl($apiAuthorizeURL);
}
```

I have added an extra **if** condition which is checking for parameter oauth_token and if there is such a parameter i'm assuming that its a login attempt from a REST API call and redirects to authorization page.

It is working, but i'm not sure if its good method or if there is any security issues since since i'm merely redirects assuming it as a REST API call.